# Does Bash have a way to get verbose output about expression evaluation?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Supposing that i want to know how my statements are axpanded and interpreted by the `bash`, how i'm supposed to act ?

Comment: If it is a shell script, start it with `#! /bin/bash -vx` as its first line. And please read http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try the debug mode:

```
bash -x script_name
```

Answer (score 6):

Inside your script

```
set -x
```

to start debug and

```
set +x
```

to stop debug mode. This way, you can debug just a part of your script instead of all of the stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing what you mean. Try `set -v`.